# Difference between defining globally and within scope

Tags: c++, global-variables, program-entry-point

So, I have a variable declared globally. For it to be used, it has to be defined. I get different results based on whether I define it globally or within scope of the *main* function.

Here's the basic code:

```
// main.cpp

//int variable = 3;

int main()
{
    //int variable = 5;

    func();

    return variable;
}

// source.cpp

#include "source.hpp"

void func()
{
    cout << variable << endl;
}

// source.hpp

#ifndef __SOURCE_HPP_INCLUDED__
#define __SOURCE_HPP_INCLUDED__

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

extern int variable;
void func();

#endif  // __SOURCE_HPP_INCLUDED__
```

So, if I define globally (outside *main*), then everything works. But if I define within *main*, then I get "undefined reference to 'variable'" errors. But I only call upon *source.cpp* when I'm inside *main*; so why do I get this error, if *variable* is defined within the same "scope" as *func*? Is it the compiler just preemptively giving the error before linking is done? Or is it related to the fact that I declared it as "extern"?

Comment: Names that contain two consecutive underscores (`__SOURCE_HPP_INCLUDED__`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved to the implementation. Don't use them.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on that? What do you mean by "implementation"? And is this a "rule-of-thumb" or do compilers parse this in a special way?

Comment: The compiler might handle them specially, but mostly it's for the benefit of the standard libraries (C and C++) which use them for internal names. If some source code defines a macro with a name like that and the library uses the same name in a header you'll get very strange error messages. If you use names like that for functions, types, or variables you risk getting name conflicts. And if your code also says `using namespace std;` you multiply those risks.

Comment: Ah, understood. Thank you for letting me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't define a global variable inside a function. You're actually defining a different, unrelated local variable that just happens to have the same name.

`func` references the global variable, so you must have a definition for it.

Comment: Okay, so it was because I declared it as a global variable in the header. That makes sense.